# How to get expires time from HttpContext in cookie-base authentication?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm building C# (.net core 2.1) Razor Page site. Login mechanism will work based on documentation from here - so token in cookies (if I understand it correctly): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Let's say I have session set to 3 min, and if user is actively using site, I'm resetting this value. If he is not, 30 seconds before token expires I want to show him message like "Do something or You will be logged out".

My problem - I can't find way to get this "expires" time.

This is how I validate and store data:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    int iCookieLifeTime = 10;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await AuthenticateUser(Input.UserName, Input.License, Input.Password, Input.KeepLogged);

        if (user == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim("Password", user.Password ) )
        };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(iCookieLifeTime)                    
        };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
            authProperties);

        return LocalRedirect(Url.GetLocalUrl(returnUrl));
    }
```

Now, how can I call AuthenticationProperties to get/set data from ExpiresUtc on all my pages? Let's say that setting is working, because I defined parameter AllowRefresh = true. But getting is something I don't know how to do.

In ideal scenario, I'd like to get it on partial pages like I get my authentication data:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor;

@if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

- There is no way to get the cookie expiration time from `HttpContext.Request.Cookies`.
- To be able to show the user a warning when the cookie is about to expire, this check needs to be implemented on client side.

**Explanation**

The server sets the expiration time when the cookie is created.
In this case, the `set-cookie` header is added to the HTTP response and sent back to the client.

Example response headers: `set-cookie: my-token: FOO; expires=Fri, 21 Apr 2023 14:11:21 GMT; domain=foobar.com; path=/; secure; samesite=strict; httponly`

The client receives the response and the cookie as well as the expiration time are stored in the browser.

When the client makes another request, the cookies are sent to the server as part of the HTTP request in the `cookies` header.

Example request headers: `cookies: my-token: FOO; my-other-token: BAR`

In this case, only the cookie name and the cookie value are sent to the server. This means the server doesn't receive the information of when the cookie will expire.